# C# DataViusalization Chart Dynamic Sizing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, resize, data-visualization

I currently have a chart created in my project as follows:

```
Chart c = new Chart{
    Width = 1000,
    Height = 1000,
};
```

This will create a chart that is 1000 pixels wide and 1000 pixels high. My question is, is there a way to have these values set dynamically so that it could take up a particular portion of the screen? For example if I wanted it to take up 80% of the screen's width and 50% of the height, is there a way to tell it to do that instead of giving static pixel values? If that cannot be done, is there a way to simply have it stretch to the size of its container in the HTML?

Comment: Please specify in which framework you are trying to achieve this. The WPF and Universal Windows UIs (both are written in XAML) do this with margins and the such, very naturally.

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio using ASP.NET MVC5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pretty much right after I posted this, I figured out a solution. The chart is displayed in the View via `<img>` tag, so I can set the style width and height within that tag to change the size of the displayed chart